# How to flip triangle colors OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, rust, graphics

Let's say I have three triangles, and I want to draw these triangles on top of each other.

I draw simple triangles, most of them will be drawn on top of each other

My triangle is black, if it falls on a triangle with black, I want to fill that side with white, if it's on the white side, I want to fill it with black. I hope this picture will help you better understand my problem

[image]

I want to invert colors, is it possible to flip pixels on the GPU.

Possible solutions - stencil buffer or [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number), but i don't even know where to start.

Comment: What is the current Rust code for this project? We might be of better help if we have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the above.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

(Note: I use the C API bellow out of convenience.)

(Disclaimer: The code snippets below are untested.)

## [Stencil test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Stencil_Test)

Make sure that your framebuffer has a stencil attachment -- depends on the way you create it.

Clear the stencil buffer to 0 (the default):

```
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Disable stencil test and color writes:

```
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
```

Make rasterized fragments 'invert' the stencil value:

```
glStencilMask(1);
glStencilOp(GL_INVERT, GL_INVERT, GL_INVERT);
```

... draw all your triangles. When done, your stencil buffer will have a non-zero value only for fragments with an odd winding number -- these are the fragments that need to be filled. This is, in essence, the mask you need to use to shade your final shape.

Enable stencil test, passing only if non-zero:

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 0 /*value*/, 1 /*mask*/);
```

Enable color writes and disable stencil writes:

```
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glStencilMask(0);
```

Now draw a full-screen quad with the color/shading that you want your shape to be (e.g. flat black in your example). Only fragments with non-zero stencil will be filled.

## [Logical operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Logical_Operation)

This is more limited in application, but is simpler and cuts the bill for what you requested. Simply enable:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
glLogicOp(GL_INVERT);
```

And proceed drawing your triangles. The color of the triangles doesn't matter, cause it'll just apply a bitwise NOT on the values in the framebuffer.

## [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)

Similar to the above, but will give different results when colors are other than black&white. You can invert through the blending equation as follows:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

Then the color will be computed as:

```
out = 1 * src - 1 * dst
```

So if you render your triangles **in white** (`src = 1`) you effectively get color inversion every time you blend a fragment:

```
out = 1 - dst
```

## Analytic triangulation

Finally you can use a geometry library to compute the resulting shape analytically, triangulate it, and draw that. However I cannot point to any readily accessible library or code to accomplish that.